# unable to open KVM when trying to VNC

Tags: kvm-virtualization, root, vnc

I am trying to open a KVM session after connecting to the remote host through VNC

Scenario: 
Server: 192.184.148.52 having a VNC server running at 192.184.148.52:2 with XYZ username and has a KVM running/ needs to crea
Host: 192.184.148.22 has a Tiger-vnc client remoting in to above server.
-Now the problem is, Everything is running fine after remoting but only thing is when I try to open up the KVM, it asks for password.
I type in the correct password for XYZ but it doesn't accept it. Whereas I type in incorrect password, it shows authentication failure.

Now, my concern= I need the authentication to go away or it should be able to accept the password.
Please also let me know if XYZ needs to be added to any specific groups or should share any extra privileges like the root user.
Any advices shall be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

If you launch kvm with **-vnc passwd** parameter, it has no vnc password, but will require one !

You should connect to the KVM's terminal (eg by using **screen /dev/pts/something**) and type "*change vnc password*" to set the password of your KVM's instance VNC Server.

Also, KVM is creating VNC listening sockets not on port 5900, but usually 5901, 5902 etc.

As a result, your VNC client shall connect to the physical machine on screen 1 or 2, like 192.184.148.52:1

KVM is usually telling you on which screen VNC is listening at startup time, and on which PTS you can join his console too.

see **man kvm** section "*-vnc display*"

Comment: okay apparently what came in handy was I tried sudo virt-manager and I was able to fix the issue.

Comment: for your future questions: if you had told us you were using virt-manager, you would have had helped a lot the people answering your question. talking about KVM may means many different virtualization managers ;)

Comment: ohh surely. I'm new and shall keep this in mind. Thanks a lot.